# Trying to make a concentric rectangular pattern in a 2d matrix with C but it's not working

Tags: c

So I need to be able to input a number M for example and it's supposed to print out M by M 2d matrix of a Concentric Rectangular Pattern.

Now my problem is my code works up until input equals 7, after that it just breaks in certain parts.

For input `7` I am expecting this output

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

but I am getting this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int M, W, W2, Z;
    int Limit = 1;
    scanf ("%d", &M);
    W2 = 0;
    int Par = 0;
    if (M % 2 == 0){
        W = M / 2;
        W2 = (M / 2) + 1;
        Par = 1;
    }
    else {
        W = (M / 2) + 1;
    }
    int matrix[M][M];
    for (int X = 1;X <= M; X++){
        Z = 1;
        for (int Y = 1;Y <= M; Y++){
            if (X == 1 || X == M){
                printf ("%d ", Z);
                
            }
            else{
                if (Y == 1 || Y == M){
                    printf ("1 ");
                    Z++;
                }
                else if (X == W && Y > W && Z > 1 && Par == 0){
                    Z--;
                    printf ("%d ", Z);
                }
                else if (X == W2 && Y > W2 && Z > 1 && Par == 1 || X == W && Y > W2 && Z > 1 && Par == 1){
                    Z--;
                    printf ("%d ", Z);
                }
                else if (Y < Limit && Y <= W){
                    printf ("%d ", Z);
                    Z++;
                }
                else if (Y >= Limit && Y <= W){
                    printf ("%d ", Z);
                }
                else if (Y >= Limit && Y <= W2){
                    printf ("%d ", Z);
                }

                
                else if (Y >= W && Z > 1){
                    printf ("%d ", Z);
                    Z--;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Limit < W && X < W){
            Limit++;
        }
        else if (Limit < W2 && X < W2){
            
        }
        else if (X >= W && Limit > 1){
            Limit--;
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried changing the Limits and changing the upper limit for the if statements but i don't know why it's not working.
edit: fixed the examples not showing correctly.

Comment: When I compile and run this program it gives the expected output. What's the problem, and what is `int matrix[M][M];` for?

Comment: int matrix [M][M]; isn't supposed to be there, forgot to remove it after i noticed i don't need it.
also check for input 7, as i said.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Did you try it with input of `7`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I mentioned in the question that everything after 7 doesn't work.

Comment: Your conditions for printing are too complicated. Undoubtedly they are wrong, but the right solution is not to analyze them to figure out what is wrong but to rewrite the program with simpler conditions.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` / `#include <stdlib.h>` / `#define max(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (b) : (a))` / `int main(void) { int M; scanf("%d", &M); for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i, putchar('\n')) for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j) printf(" %d", (M+1 - max(abs(2*i-M+1), abs(2*j-M+1)))/2); }`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Jesus that's actually so much easier. yeah, i should have thought of that, arrays are still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @Jhinius Look at Eric's solution above too. Not even using the `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

As per me you have complicated the code by addressing every single row and column individually, a simplified code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a, n;

int main() {
printf("Enter the Number: ");
scanf("%d",&a);

if(a%2 == 0)
{
    n = a/2;
    printf("\n The Output is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
            int z = i;
            if (z > 2 * n - 1 - i) {
                z = 2 * n - 1 - i;
            }
            if (z > j) {
                z = j;
            }
            if (z > 2 * n - 1 - j) {
                z = 2 * n - 1 - j;
            }
            int value = z+1;

            printf("%d ", value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
else
{
  n = (a/2)+1;
  printf("\n The Output is: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n - 1; j++) {
            int z = i;
            if (z > 2 * n - 2 - i) {
                z = 2 * n - 2 - i;
            }
            if (z > j) {
                z = j;
            }
            if (z > 2 * n - 2 - j) {
                z = 2 * n - 2 - j;
            }
            int value = z+1;

            printf("%d ", value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

However to answer your question. You been facing the issue coz firstly you haven't declared W2 for odd inputs, i.e. when (M%2 !=0) however the reason for getting skipped numbers in rows is because there is no declaration or operation when "Z" goes below or equal to one, thus no output is printed and Y increases. The method you have opted is quite exhausting for you are addressing every column indvidually.